# Getting Error while plotting contour map as (Error in if (any(h <= 0)) stop("bandwidths must be strictly positive") : in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

For the below data

```
       > head(df)

      Date Longitude Latitude Elevation Max.Temperature Min.Temperature Precipitation     Wind Relative.Humidity    Solar  RO
     1 2014-07-01   77.1875  7.96184     -9999          27.725          26.673  16.115560560 8.395378         0.8132272 23.08192 Yes
     2 2014-07-02   77.1875  7.96184     -9999          27.931          26.897   0.700378560 8.062267         0.8074675 21.48473 Yes
     3 2014-07-03   77.1875  7.96184     -9999          28.179          26.686   0.000000000 9.465022         0.8107901 24.14900  No
     4 2014-07-04   77.1875  7.96184     -9999          27.657          26.545   0.003433226 9.397203         0.8195020 23.42036 Yes
     5 2014-07-05   77.1875  7.96184     -9999          27.157          26.490   1.541518560 8.903047         0.8385059 23.90545 Yes
     6 2014-07-06   77.1875  7.96184     -9999          27.308          26.481   0.000000000 8.617348         0.8205267 23.96318  No
```

I have created an map using ggmap

```
     > Precip_map<-get_map(location="india",maptype="satellite",zoom=12)

        Map from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=india&zoom=12&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=satellite&language=en-EN&sensor=false

     > ggmap(Precip_map, extent = "device") + geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), colour = "red", 
     +     alpha = 0.1, size = 2, data = df)

     Warning message:
    In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
    Removed 1106 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

drawn contour map

```
    > ggmap(Precip_map, extent = "device") + geom_density2d(data = df, 
    +     aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), size = 0.3) + stat_density2d(data = df, 
    +     aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01, 
    +     bins = 16, geom = "polygon") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red", 
    +     guide = FALSE) + scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)

     Error in if (any(h <= 0)) stop("bandwidths must be strictly positive") : 
     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
     Error in if (any(h <= 0)) stop("bandwidths must be strictly positive") : 
     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
     In addition: Warning message:
     In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
     Removed 1106 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density2d).
     Warning message:
     In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
     Removed 1106 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density2d).
```

I dont know exactly where i am lacking.. i am new to this mapping.. please assist me. Also, I want to plot df$Precipitation in this contour map.

Comment: Does the answer [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg227199.html) (from the r-help mailing list) help you? You might have to try str(df) to see whether your variables are really numeric.

Comment: Thanks maj - sometimes it's the simple fixes we don't think about

Answer (score 6):

The `lat, long` values are same across the entire dataset. Hence, the variance in both the `lat` and `long` direction is zero, so a bandwidth for the kernel density estimate (KDE) can't be calculated.

Hence, you are getting the error `bandwidths must be strictly positive`.

For calculating 2-D KDEs, the variance in both x and y direction need to positive. You are getting the error twice as in your case variance in both directions are 0.

Comment: So how do we deal if real life data effectively has 0 variance? Should we add tiny noise for kde to be able to be estimated?

Comment: I am not sure whether KDE is the correct option when there is zero variance. But if you must calculate a KDE, adding a tiny noise will stop the errors from appearing. But ,the results may not be meaningful.