# Plot one data frame column against all other columns using ggplots and showing densities in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, probability-density

I have a data frame with 20 columns, and I want to plot one specific column (called BB) against each single column in the data frame. The plots I need are probability density plots, and I’m using the following code to generate one plot (plotting columns BB vs. AA as an example):

```
mydata = as.data.frame(fread("filename.txt")) #read my data as data frame

#function to calculate density
get_density <- function(x, y, n = 100) {
  dens <- MASS::kde2d(x = x, y = y, n = n)
  ix <- findInterval(x, dens$x)
  iy <- findInterval(y, dens$y)
  ii <- cbind(ix, iy)
  return(dens$z[ii])
}
set.seed(1)

#define the x and y of the plot; x = column called AA; y = column called BB
xy1 <- data.frame(
  x = mydata$AA,
  y = mydata$BB
)

#call function get_density to calculate density for the defined x an y
xy1$density <- get_density(xy1$x, xy1$y) 

#Plot
ggplot(xy1) + geom_point(aes(x, y, color = density), size = 3, pch = 20) + scale_color_viridis() +
  labs(title = "BB vs. AA") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="AA") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="BB")
```

**Would appreciate it if someone can suggest a method to produce multiple plot of BB against every other column, using the above density function and ggplot command.** I tried adding a loop, but found it too complicated especially when defining the x and y to be plotted or calling the density function.

Comment: Can you post your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't provide sample data, I'll demo on `mtcars`. We convert the data to long format, calculate the densities, and make a faceted plot. We plot the `mpg` column against all others.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtlong = gather(mtcars, key = "var", value = "value", -mpg) %>%
    group_by(var) %>%
    mutate(density = get_density(value, mpg))

ggplot(mtlong, aes(x = value, y = mpg, color = density)) +
    geom_point(pch = 20, size = 3) +
    labs(x = "") +
    facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried the following: mtlong = gather(mydata, key = "var", value = "value", -mydata$BB) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate(density = get_density(mydata$BB, value)), and got this error: Error: `NULL` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a double vector

Comment: Don't use `data$` inside `dplyr` verbs. You seem to have replaced `mpg` with `mydata$BB`. `mpg` should be replaced with `BB`. Only use `mydata$` if my code uses `mtcars$`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this will work. I got another error after doing the change you suggested: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :  Evaluation error: bandwidths must be strictly positive. What does that mean?

Comment: Sounds like an error in `kde2d`. You can [see it here in the kde2d code](https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/master/R/kde2d.R).

Comment: Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: A typical debugging process would have you isolate the problem by identifying a column that has the issue (subset your data and try different subsets). Then see what's weird about that input. You can also search for the error message. [This question would suggest that maybe one of your columns is a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39966958/903061) and can't be used. If you still have trouble, ask a new question and post a minimal example data set that reproduces the problem.