# brushedPoints are wrong for ggplot data when faceted via gather()

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, facet

I have been having good luck in Shiny with faceted data.  I create plots, and have the selected (i.e. brushed) data show up in a table below the plot.

I have recently tried to do this same operation with slightly more complex data.  I want to select a single field in the data, and then generate plots of all of the data against that one field.  I learned how to do that via [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840017/plot-one-data-frame-column-against-all-other-columns-using-ggplots-and-showing-d) .

It seemed to work when I put it in my app, except I noticed that on certain plots, 1) when I tried to select ALL of the points, none would show up (below), or

[image: All points selected, but none shown in table]

... 2 ) if I tried to select empty space, all of the data was selected (below).

[image: Empty space selected, but all data shown in table]

It seems to me that that the brush coordinates are not accurately converting into data coordinates.  For example, here's some of the data from the 'disp' plot which is illustrated as failing (it's ordered by value - 71.1 is the smallest value):

```
mpg  var value
33.9 disp  71.1
30.4 disp  75.7
32.4 disp  78.7
27.3 disp  79.0
30.4 disp  95.1
22.8 disp 108.0
```

When I have attempted to select all of the points in the disp plot (i.e. the first image), the values for the brush are below (xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax all seem to match my selection).  However, I don't know how the drawn box coordinates are translated into a data selection - I'm really getting out of my depth here:

```
> fancybrush
$`xmin`
[1] 51.18154
$xmax
[1] 482.1583
$ymin
[1] 9.225
$ymax
[1] 35.075
$panelvar1
[1] "disp"
$coords_css
$coords_css$`xmin`
[1] 721
$coords_css$xmax
[1] 898
$coords_css$ymin
[1] 24.24657
$coords_css$ymax
[1] 121.9497
$coords_img
$coords_img$`xmin`
[1] 721
$coords_img$xmax
[1] 898
$coords_img$ymin
[1] 24.24657
$coords_img$ymax
[1] 121.9497
img_css_ratio
$img_css_ratio$`x`
[1] 1
$img_css_ratio$y
[1] 1
$mapping
$mapping$`x`
[1] "value"
$mapping$y
[1] "mpg"
$mapping$panelvar1
[1] "var"
$domain
$domain$`left`
[1] -23.6
$domain$right
[1] 495.6
$domain$bottom
[1] 9.225
$domain$top
[1] 35.075
$range
$range$`left`
[1] 690.2876
$range$right
[1] 903.5204
$range$bottom
[1] 121.9497
$range$top
[1] 24.24657
$log
$log$`x`
NULL
$log$y
NULL
$direction
[1] "xy"
$brushId
[1] "fancybrush"
$outputId
[1] "fancyPlot"
```

This is getting to be a bit of a time-suck for me, but I seem to be close enough that I'm pretty sure it's possible.  If anyone can suggest what I might need to do to fix it, I'd love to hear from you.

Below is the smallest possible reproducible sample code I can make that illustrates the 'simple' faceting (that works) directly above the 'fancy' faceting, which fails.  There are a few places where I set global variables so I could see what the values were.

Apologies for the long post - I hope I've been as clear as possible.  Thanks for reading this far.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(h1("Simple Facet"),p("These plots facet mtcars by CYL", plotOutput("simpleFacetPlot",brush = "simplebrush"), dataTableOutput("simpleFacetTable"))),
  div(h1("Fancy Facet"),p("These plots plot all other columns against MPG", plotOutput("fancyPlot",brush = "fancybrush"), dataTableOutput("fancyTable")))
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  ##### functions to get the data
  getSimpleData <-function(){
    thisData = mtcars
    thisData<<-thisData
    return(thisData)
  } 
  getFancyData <-function(coreField = NULL){
    thisData = mtcars
    thisData = thisData[!is.na(thisData[coreField]),]
    thisDataRes = thisData %>% gather(-coreField , key = "var", value = "value")  
    thisDataRes<<-thisDataRes
    return(thisDataRes)
  }
  #####  blocks to watch for the selections
  simpleSelected <- reactive({
    input$simplebrush
    thisSimpleData = getSimpleData()
    simpleBrushed=brushedPoints(thisSimpleData,
                          input$simplebrush,
                          xvar = "wt",
                          yvar = "mpg")
    return(simpleBrushed)
  })
  fancySelected <- reactive({
    input$fancybrush
    fancybrush<<-input$fancybrush
    thisFancyData = getFancyData(coreField = 'mpg')
    fancyBrushed=brushedPoints(thisFancyData,
                          input$fancybrush,
                          xvar = "var",
                          yvar = "mpg")
    return(fancyBrushed)
  })

 ##### blocks to generate the plots
  output$simpleFacetPlot <- renderPlot({
    #just force faceting on cylinder for the simple plot
    simpleFacetPlot = ggplot(data = getSimpleData(), aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ cyl) 
    return(simpleFacetPlot)
  })
  output$fancyPlot <- renderPlot({
    fancyPlot <- ggplot(data = getFancyData(coreField = 'mpg'), aes(x = value, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ var) 
    return(fancyPlot)
  })

  #####blocks to print the selection output
  output$fancyTable <- renderDataTable({
    return(fancySelected())
  })  
  output$simpleFacetTable <- renderDataTable({
    return(simpleSelected())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```